# DOM PHP Web Crawler converting object to int

Tags: php

I have this web crawler works awesomely fine.. 
so i thought of adding some code to get the first top 10 statements to get extracted..

But unfortunately, it gave an error of

> Notice: Object of class simple_html_dom_node could not be converted to int in C:\xampp\htdocs\usmlebuzz\index.php on line 392

Line 392 is `if($element==10){`

its clearly telling me that i m trying to use an object as integer. but the real problem is how to convert this object to int.

code goes as:

```
<?php
    require('dom/simple_html_dom.php'); 
    $html = file_get_html('http://www.usmleforum.com/forum/index.php?forum=1');

    foreach($html->find('td.FootNotes2 a') as $element) { 
        $element->href = "http://www.usmleforum.com" . $element->href; 
        echo '<li target="_blank" class="itemtitle">';
        echo '<span class="item_new">new</span>';
        echo $element;
        echo '</li>';
        if($element==10){
            break;
        }                           
    }
?>
```

Any Help is Appreciable..

Comment: Can you post the full error here. with line file ....

Comment: No its telling you you are trying to assing an object to an integer

Comment: And just as note: if  `$element` is an object , why do you this: `if($element==10)` ??

Comment: `Notice: Object of class simple_html_dom_node could not be converted to int in C:\xampp\htdocs\usmlebuzz\index.php on line 392`

Comment: Now if you can tell us which is line 392 in the 16 lines of code you have shown us

Comment: actually it extracts all statements in the class.Footnotes2.. so, i trying to tell it to extract only first 10 statements...

Comment: @RiggsFolly that the `if (element ==10)` line

Comment: And is that when the error happened?

Comment: Did the error start happening when you coded the `if($element==10){` statement

Comment: yes, it happened then only.. i even tried removing that, and it worked fine

Comment: **DUH** Well did that not give you a bit of a clue about what might be causing the probem?

Comment: you haven't read the question .. did you? i said `its clearly telling me that i m trying to use an object as integer. but the real problem is how to convert this object to int.`

Comment: See @JustOnUnderMillions answer. That will fix your coding problem. Dont forget to accept the answer if it does fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to fix this, if i get it right :-)

```
require_once('dom/simple_html_dom.php'); 
$html = file_get_html('http://www.usmleforum.com/forum/index.php?forum=1');
$elementCount=0;
foreach($html->find('td.FootNotes2 a') as $element) { 
 $elementCount++;
 $element->href = "http://www.usmleforum.com" . $element->href; 
 echo '<li target="_blank" class="itemtitle">';
 echo '<span class="item_new">new</span>';
 echo $element;
 echo '</li>';
 if($elementCount==10){
    break;
 }            
}
```

If you have a function like
`function file_get_html(){}`

and it will be included via `include 'myfile.php';` more than once, 
you can prevent declare of existing function with:

```
if(!function_exists('file_get_html')) {
 function file_get_html(){
   /*function code*/
 }
}
```

Comment: After pulling a few teeth, I think we can safely say this is a solution to the OP's coding problems at least

Comment: @RiggsFolly Real answers for real problems ;-)

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions hey, @JustOnUnderMillions thanks for the sol. but another thing came up.. like i added another script like that in the same page for extraction another site, and it came error like, `Cannot redeclare file_get_html() `

Comment: @harishk, add around the function definition of `file_get_html(){}`  this `if(!function_exists('file_get_html')){   file_get_html(){}  }`, so the function will ony one time declared

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions dude, can you update the answer the same... thanks

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions so, pasting the dom crawler code in the "function code" place will do it?

Comment: @harishk Thing you should do just `require_once('dom/simple_html_dom.php');`, that should work too.   `simple_html_dom.php` is from an external source, coded by someone else, or?

Comment: downloaded it dude..online

Comment: Then change `require` to `require_once` and you are fine.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so as far as i understand, the solution to your problem is:
Convert:

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.usmleforum.com/forum/index.php?forum=1');
```

to:

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.usmleforum.com/forum/index.php?forum=1')->plaintext;
```

then use $html=(float)$html; and use this as integer or float number. this may solve your issue as it did for me.